# Robot on same network (Ubuntu/Fedora)

Tags: ros, fedora, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I'm using a robot with a ubuntu 14,04 and ros indigo and my own computer with  Fedora 23 and a source install of ros indigo.
I'm trying to connect them using the wifi network generated by my robot.

I fixed the env variable for both platform. On my computer with a fixed IP of 10.0.0.115 :

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.3:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.115
ROS_IP=10.0.0.115
```

On the robot, I did :

```
robot@ROBOT:~$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.3:11311
robot@ROBOT:~$ export ROS_IP=10.0.0.3
robot@ROBOT:~$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.3
```

After this. if I launch the roscore on the robot, I can listen to everything that is publish from the robot on my computer but everything that is publish from my computer to the robot is lost.

If I run roswtf on my computer it doesn't return any errors while, on the robot, roswtf return this :

```
Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /rostopic_8305_1450259505852

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/rostopic_8305_1450259505852/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rostopic_8305_1450259505852/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://10.0.0.115:42198]
 * service [/rostopic_8305_1450259505852/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rostopic_8305_1450259505852/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://10.0.0.115:42198]
```

I tried the same step I used on my fedora on a Ubuntu computer and the publishing from the computer worked fine. I did very step that is on [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and they all worked apart from the netcat one. I can write from my computer to the robot alright but is I open a port o my computer using `nc -l 1234` and try to write to it on the robot with `netcat 10.0.0.115 1234` then the command return without doing anything :

```
robot@ROBOT netcat 10.0.0.115 1234
robot@ROBOT:~$
```

It seems that the robot cannot connect the topic published from my computer and I'm at a loss as to why. Any help is appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222622/robot-on-same-network-(ubuntu/fedora)/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the solution, the ssh server needs to be running on fedora :

```
service sshd start
```

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0